# How to count the number of rows with a date from a certain year in CodeIgniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have the following query.

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM iplog.persons WHERE begin_date LIKE '2014%'');
```

I need to count the number of columns with a begin_date in the year 2014.

When I run this script I'm getting an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '2014' (T_LNUMBER) in C:\xampp\htdocs\iPlog2\application\controllers\stat.php on line 12

I was trying to change my CI script to

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM iplog.persons WHERE begin_date LIKE "2014%"');
```

but it caused an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, count ROWS:

So for that, just count the number of rows you have based on a condition:

```
$year = '2014'
$this->db->from('iplog');
$this->db->like('begin_date', $year); 
$query = $this->db->get();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: Not only is this inefficient, but it also produces the **wrong** result with certain database drivers (PDO/SQLite and possibly others will give you the wrong result)

Answer (score 2):

First, you have a simple typo regarding the use of single quotes.  Your complete sql string should be double quoted so that your value-quoting can be single quoted.

Second, you are using inappropriate query logic.  When you want to make a comparison on a DATE or DATETIME type column, you should NEVER be using `LIKE`.  There are specific MYSQL functions dedicated to handling these types.  In your case, you should be using `YEAR()` to isolate the year component of your `begin_date` values.

Resource: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-year-function.php

You could write the raw query like this: (`COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` are equivalent)

```
$count = $this->db
              ->query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM persons WHERE YEAR(begin_date) = 2014")
              ->row()
              ->COUNT;
```

Or if you want to employ Codeigniter methods to build the query:

```
$count = $this->db
              ->where("YEAR(begin_date) = 2014")
              ->count_all_results("persons");
```

---

You could return all of the values in all of the rows that qualify, but that would mean asking the database for values that you have no intention of using -- this is not best practice.  **I do not recommend the following**:

```
$count = $this->db
              ->get_where('persons', 'YEAR(begin_date) = 2014')
              ->num_rows();
```

For this reason, you should not be generating a fully populated result set then calling `num_rows()` or `count()` when you have no intention of using the values in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Replace quotes like this :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM iplog.persons WHERE begin_date LIKE '2014%'");
```

Double quote your entire query, then simple quote your LIKE criteria.